# Adding and removing new value inside a dropdown list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

guys just want to check, if it is possible to add in new data through the webpage and save it permanently. For example in my dropdown list, I have 3 person names,  John, Tom, and Jerry. And in this dropdown list, I want to add a new person name called Keith and remove Jerry name from the dropdown list.

Here is how it look like for my side now:

```
<div class="input-group">
          <label><b>List of Class leader:</b></label>
      <select name="class_leader" id="class_leader" class="form-control" >
                 <option value="John" >John</option>
                 <option value="Jerry">Jerry</option>
                 <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
              </select> 
        </div>
```

So is it possible to do an edit on this? Like maybe create a new page or something so that I could edit it

Could you guys give me some opinion on what to do? And maybe give some example if possible so that I would understand it better.

Comment: So what's wrong if you replace `Jerry` with  `Keith`

Comment: You can use some lines of Java script to do this and then use some database functions to save it

Comment: @MrDeveloper sorry I don't quite get what you mean, I just want to ask if it is possible to remove the name Jerry in my dropdown list and add in Keith inside. Something like update and delete function but changing it in the dropdown list

Comment: @SagarGautam Could you give me some example of javascript or link so that I could do it?

Comment: Add `onclick="myFunction()"` in <select> tag and then try this: `<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("class_leader");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Jerry";
    option.text = "Keith";
    x.add(option);
}
</script>` This will add two new names in `<select>` tag.

Comment: @HirenGohel But if the user wanted to add a new person name, wouldn't he need to enter codes to do that?

Comment: @Dkna so you want user can add any name by himself in select box?

Comment: Yup if that is possible, sorry everybody if I didn't say properly in my question

Comment: Yes, even i didn't understand exactly what are you trying to say! Anyway no problem!

Comment: Try: add this `<input type="text" name="name" id="name">` and then use this: `<script>
function myFunction() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var x = document.getElementById("class_leader");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = name;
    x.add(option);
}
</script>`

Comment: Erm possible to put it as an answer? I won't be trying it today since it quite late on my side here, just want to get some ideas on how to do it. Will do it tomorrow. Just want to get some rough ideas so that I know how to do it

Comment: I will suggest you that add input box to enter name and then add it to select box ok? i'll add my answer!

Comment: Sure, will try all the answer tomorrow, thank you all for helping me, will let you know again how it is tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways, if this list needs to be saved permanently then the way to go about it is with a database.

In Laravel you can create something called models and migrations. You could create a model called `ClassLeader` with a migration by using the `php artisan make:model ClassLeader -m` command. This will create a model aswell as a migration.

Now in your migration file you can add the schematics for your table, I would recommend something like this.

```
//...
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('class_leaders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
//...
```

Now you can use the command `php artisan migrate` which will migrate this new schematic to the database allowing you to store the data there.

You can now use the model to access this table with Eloquent by adding `use App\ClassLeader;` to the top of whatever file needs to use it (Most likely a controller) and then using it like so `ClassLeader::find(1);` or you can use it directly by using the full namespace as such `App\ClassLeader::find(1);`.

I would then recommend you add a form that submits a new ClassLeader to the database and you can do that within your controller like so

```
//...
$class_leader = new ClassLeader;
$class_leader->name = 'NAME HERE';
$class_leader->save(); // Saves this ClassLeader to the database
//...
```

Then to show all class leaders you can do something like this in your view.

```
//...
@foreach(App\ClassLeader::all() as $leader)
    <option value="{{ $leader->id }}">{{ $leader->name }}</option>
@endforeach
//...
```

All this does is run through the entire table of class leaders and shows them via a `option` DOM element.

Hopefully this answer can lead you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for giving some ideas in doing it and also with the clear explanation, will try this tomorrow, since it late. Didn't thought I could do this way, kept on thinking that some javascript is needed here. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Dkna Javascript would only be needed if you *need* to do it in the same page without a page reload, then you can do the same thing with Ajax with some small changes to the code I provided. When you've tried it out, be sure to let me know if it helped you or if you have any more problems :). Merry Christmas.

Comment: Thank you, Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Hi Classified, the codes work really well for me thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you want it to be, but i'll just gave you an idea to add names in select box using JS. Please see below code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
     <input type='text' id='idea' />
     <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
     <select name="class_leader" id="class_leader" class="form-control">
             <option value="John" >John</option>
             <option value="Jerry">Jerry</option>
             <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
     </select> 
</form>

<script>
   document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
   //First things first, we need our text:
   var text = document.getElementById("idea").value; //.value gets input values
   //Now construct a quick list element
   var x = document.getElementById("class_leader");
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = text;
   x.add(option);

}
```

Here, you need to add input box and user will enter any name in it and after press add, it'll add to the select box!

Hope this will helps you!!

Comment: Hi HirenGohel, thank you for helping me as well, but it seems the javascript has some error on my side so I can't use it but anyways thank you for helping